# How can I spawn a seperate terminal in order to debug my TUI application in NodeJS with ink react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, process, ipc

I am building an application with Ink react on a terminal. I'd like to have a dedicated and seperate terminal to output any logs I want from the main application. In order to do that, I went to try the `"ipc"` stdio option from the `spawn` function:

```
import { spawn } from "child_process";
import type { ChildProcess } from "child_process";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import path from "path";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export function useExternalDebugTerminal(): ChildProcess {
    const terminal = spawn("x-terminal-emulator", ["-e", `yarn node ${path.resolve(__dirname, "childTerm.js")}`], {
        stdio: [0, 1, 2, "ipc"],
        detached: true
    });

    return terminal;
}

const term = useExternalDebugTerminal();

term.send("Hello, child process!\n");
```

And here is the childTerm.js code:

```
import process from "process";

process.on("message", (msg) => {
    console.log("Received message in child:", msg);
});
```

The result is a terminal that briefly spawns without outputting anything.

When I added these to the parent:

```
term.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Error in parent process:", err);
});

term.on("exit", (code, signal) => {
    console.log(`Child process exited with code ${code} and signal ${signal}`);
});
```

This was the output:

```
Child process exited with code 134 and signal null
```

I am losing my mind on this problem. I thought about using sockets, which will be easier and surely will work, but I am still haunted by this IPC thing and I want to know the solution to this insane problem.

Thank you